# How to copy only few files?

Tags: python, file, copy

I want to copy only first 50 files. I know how to copy the files but how do I copy only first 50 files?
This is the code I'm using for copying the file. It copies all the files present in the folder. I want to copy only first 50 files.

```
import sys, os, time, shutil
print time.ctime()
path = "C:\\temp"
files = os.listdir(path)
print len(files)
if len(files)<=0:
   print'No Files Present'
else:
   files.sort()
   fileobj = open("log.txt",'a')
   for eachfilename in files:
      src = path+'\\'+eachfilename
      temp = "C:\\Backup\\" +eachfilename
      dst = "C:\\Dest\\" +eachfilename
      shutil.copy(src,temp)
      retrn_val = shutil.move(src, dst)
      print retrn_val
      print "File moved:",eachfilename 
      if retrn_val:
         fileobj.write(eachfilename+','+'moved Sucessfully'+'\n')
      else:
         fileobj.write(eachfilename+','+'failed to move'+'\n')

print time.ctime()
```

Is there any function to specify number of files to copy?

Comment: I'm a newbie to python, that's why so silly question

Comment: @AndreasJung flagging for useless comment and downvote. Try to be more accommodating in your life and lets make SO welcoming to beginners and advanced players alike.

Answer (score 3):

You could replace

```
files = os.listdir(path)
```

with

```
files = os.listdir(path)[:50]
```

This would [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation) the list and limit the number of files to 50.

Comment: +1 this is pretty much the answer. alternative, I was going to suggest: `for eachfilename in files[:50]` If the OP wanted to know the total number of files, but only wanted to iterate of the first 50.

Comment: Thanks alot. I'm a newbie to python, that's why so silly question.